# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Insufficient funds

Tags: node.js, promise, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js

I am using web3.js v1.0.0-beta.34 & nodeJS v9.11.2 to execute a smart contract on the Kovan testnet. The same method works for me on Ropsten with another smart contract. Here are the two errors I get via the callback:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Returned error: Insufficient
> funds. The account you tried to send transaction from does not have
> enough funds. Required 183675000000 and got: 0.

> (node:15422) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
> rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
> function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
> not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

This is my smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Test2 {
    address public customer;
    bytes32 public productName;

    struct Box {
        uint size;
    }
    Box public box;

    constructor() public {
        box.size = 3;
        customer = 0xDa3E3C75....;
        productName = "0x576...";
    }

    function changeBox(uint _change) public {
        box.size = _change;
    }

    function getBox() public returns (uint) {
        return box.size;
    }  
}
```

And here is the JavaScript code to make a transaction and execute the `function changeBox` with web3 and node:

```
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
var Web3 = require('web3'); 


var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://kovan.infura.io/api_key'));
const contractAddress = '0x36075430619b21Fff798454e2D5C81E9C18DEe81';
var contractABI = new web3.eth.Contract(
    [...json abi...], contractAddress);
var boxNum;


function changeBox(boxNum, callback) {
    web3.eth.defaultAccount = "0x002D189c25958c60...";
    const account = '0x002D189c2595...';
    const privateKey = Buffer.from('240462d5...', 'hex');
    const contractFunction = contractABI.methods.changeBox(Number(boxNum));
    const functionAbi = contractFunction.encodeABI();
    let estimatedGas;
    let nonce;
    
    contractFunction.estimateGas(function(error, gasAmount) {
        if(!error) {
            console.log('Estimated Gas : ' + gasAmount);
            estimatedGas = gasAmount + 10000;
            console.log('New Gas: ' + estimatedGas);

            web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account).then(_nonce => { 
                nonce = _nonce.toString(16);
                console.log("Nonce: " + nonce);
                
                const txParams = {
                    gasPrice: estimatedGas,
                    gasLimit: 5000000,
                    to: contractAddress,
                    data: functionAbi,
                    from: account,
                    nonce: '0x' + nonce
                };
                const tx = new Tx(txParams);
                tx.sign(privateKey);
                const serializedTx = tx.serialize();
                web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex')).on('receipt', receipt => {
                    callback(receipt);
                    
                });
            });  
        } 
        else {
            callback(error);
        }
    });
}

//calling the contract with value 6
changeBox(6, function(err, data) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(data);
    }
    else {
        console.log(err);
    }});
```

Answer (score 5):

`sendSignedTransaction` returns a [promiEvent](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/callbacks-promises-events.html) onto which you can chain `then` and `catch`:

```
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
  .on('receipt', receipt => {
    callback(receipt);
  }).then(() => {
    // success
  }).catch(() => {
    // fail
  });
```

An Unhandled promise rejection is thrown because the promise gets rejected but there is no `catch` handler.

Comment: But what should the catch do exactly? Like I said: exactly the same method, but with other parameters, works on another `smartcontract` & its `contract function`

Comment: I had a different unhandled promise rejection, and this code update fixed the error.  It will also be helpful for another aspect of my code. Thank you very much!